# Сравнить 2 даты javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Мне нужен календарь, который выбирает 2 даты, а по клику на чекбокс, добавляет 3 дня ко второму значению, и отнимает от первого 3. Все работает, только когда я использую текущую дату, он может выбрать уже прошедшую дату, которая `disabled`.

Как сделать проверку эта дата уже прошла или нет?

Не могу понять как сравнить даты. Кто знает, подскажите

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var datepicker = $('.calendar_min').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        range: true,
        toggleSelected: true,
        minDate: new Date(),
        multipleDatesSeparator: ",",
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
            if(date) {
                $("#dateRange").val(formattedDate);

            }
        }
    }).data('datepicker');

    $('.datepicker--cells').on('click', function () {

        $("#date3Range").prop('checked',false);

    });


    $("#date3Range").on('click', function(){

        if($('#dateRange').val()){
            var str = $('#dateRange').val();
            var arrDate = str.split(',');
            if(arrDate.length == 2){
                if(this.checked){
                   var selectedDate = new Date(arrDate[0]);
                   selectedDate = selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() - 3);
                   var selectedDate2 = new Date(arrDate[1]);
                   selectedDate2 = selectedDate2.setDate(selectedDate2.getDate() + 3);
               }else {
                   var selectedDate = new Date(arrDate[0]);
                   selectedDate = selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 3);
                   var selectedDate2 = new Date(arrDate[1]);
                   selectedDate2 = selectedDate2.setDate(selectedDate2.getDate() - 3);
               }
               datepicker.selectDate(new Date(selectedDate));
               datepicker.selectDate(new Date(selectedDate2));
           } else {
               this.checked = false;
           }
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<input class="calendar_min" type="hidden">

<h4>+/- 3 дня</h4>

<input type="checkbox" id="date3Range">
<input type="hidden" id="dateRange">
```

Comment: Непонятно чего ты хочешь добиться, чтобы нельзя было таким образом выбрать даты раньше текущей? и что должно произойти в таком случае, на текущей дате должны останавливаться?

Comment: да, вы все правильно поняли, не получается такое сделать, разные значения даты  у одного дня

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С минимальными изменениями в коде.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var start, end;
  var datepicker = $('.calendar_min').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    range: true,
    toggleSelected: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    multipleDatesSeparator: ",",
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(formattedDate, date, inst) {
      if (date) {
        $("#dateRange").val(formattedDate);

      }
    }
  }).data('datepicker');

  $('.datepicker--cells').on('click', function() {

    $("#date3Range").prop('checked', false);

  });


  $("#date3Range").on('click', function() {

    if ($('#dateRange').val()) {
      var str = $('#dateRange').val();
      var arrDate = str.split(',');
      if (arrDate.length == 2) {
        if (this.checked) {
          var selectedDate =  new Date(arrDate[0]);
          start = new Date(arrDate[0]);
          selectedDate = selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() - 3);
          if (selectedDate < Date.now()) selectedDate = Date.now(); //добавлена проверка
          var selectedDate2 =  new Date(arrDate[1]);
          end = new Date(arrDate[1]);
          selectedDate2 = selectedDate2.setDate(selectedDate2.getDate() + 3);
        } else {
          var selectedDate = start;
          var selectedDate2 = end;
        }
        datepicker.selectDate(new Date(selectedDate));
        datepicker.selectDate(new Date(selectedDate2));
      } else {
        this.checked = false;
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<input class="calendar_min" type="hidden">

<h4>+/- 3 дня</h4>

<input type="checkbox" id="date3Range">
<input type="hidden" id="dateRange">
```

Comment: К сожалению это не работает. При выборе 11-12, при `checked=false` неправильно работает. Не возвращается к выбранным датам ранее

Comment: @max что именно не так?

Comment: я предполагаю что `new Date` & `Date.now` дает разные результаты

Comment: @max я имею ввиду где неверное поведение? внес еще одну правку

Comment: расскажите пожалуйста что именно было не так? В чем была проблема?

Comment: @max сейчас нормально? последняя правка была связана с тем, что при снятии чекбокса происходило обратное прибавление/вычитание, а нужно было откатываться к значению которое было до установки галочки

Comment: Сейчас все круто, пытаюсь понять как это получилось

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сравнить дату с текущей, достаточно просто использовать `new Date`:

```
new Date() > new Date(selectedDate2)
```

Comment: Я так пытался сделать, но почему-то не совпадают даты глобального `new Date` и выбранного числа из календаря. Если не сложно, можете пример сделать?